# How can I use enum as bool flag?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SceneFader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CanvasGroup canvasGroup;
    public bool fadeAutomatically;
    public float fadeTime;
    // Stores the currently running routine to be able to stop/cancel it
    private Coroutine _currentRoutine;
    // Stores the current direction
    private bool _currentDirection;
    // Used for the automatic switch to determine the next direction
    private bool _nextDirection;

    private void Start()
    {  
            SceneManager.sceneLoaded += SceneManager_sceneLoaded;
    }

    public enum FadeDirection
    {
        In,
        Out
    }

    public IEnumerator FadeAndLoadScene(bool fadeDirection, string sceneToLoad)
    {
        yield return Fade(canvasGroup, fadeDirection, false);

        SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneToLoad);
    }
    private void SceneManager_sceneLoaded(Scene arg0, LoadSceneMode arg1)
    {
        if (MenuController.LoadSceneForSavedGame == true)
        {
            var saveLoad = GameObject.Find("Save System").GetComponent<SaveLoad>();
            saveLoad.Load();
        }
    }

    private void StartFade(bool isIn, bool autoSwitch)
    {
        // Another routine running already?
        if (_currentRoutine != null)
        {
            // Different direction?
            if (_currentDirection != isIn)
            {
                // Interrupt the current routine
                StopCoroutine(_currentRoutine);

                // And start a new one
                _currentRoutine = StartCoroutine(Fade(canvasGroup, isIn, autoSwitch));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise directly start the first routine
            _currentRoutine = StartCoroutine(Fade(canvasGroup, isIn, autoSwitch));
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!fadeAutomatically)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))
            {
                StartFade(false, fadeAutomatically);
            }

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
            {
                StartFade(true, fadeAutomatically);
            }
        }
        else // fadeAutomatically
        {
            StartFade(_nextDirection, fadeAutomatically);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator Fade(CanvasGroup canvasGroup, bool isIn, bool autoSwitch)
    {
        // Store the current fading direction
        _currentDirection = isIn;

        // Determine start and end value depending on the fading direction
        var startValue = isIn ? 0 : 1;
        var targetValue = isIn ? 1 : 0;

        // Get the so far elapsed time according to the current alpha
        // It is the fadeTime multiplied by the already added or removed alpha
        var elapsedTime = fadeTime * (isIn ? canvasGroup.alpha : (1 - canvasGroup.alpha));
        while (elapsedTime <= fadeTime)
        {
            // Use Maths.Lerp to linear interpolate between the start and end value
            canvasGroup.alpha = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, targetValue, elapsedTime / fadeTime);

            // For "skipping" one single frame you can simply return null
            yield return null;

            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        }

        // To be sure to end with clean values
        canvasGroup.alpha = targetValue;

        // Should we automatically switch the direction?
        if (autoSwitch) _nextDirection = !isIn;

        // Reset the current routine (see below)
        // Not sure if this is really necessary, I believe it will reset anyway 
        // as soon as the routine has finished .. but just to be sure
        _currentRoutine = null;
    }   
}
```

I added this enum and using it : lines 24 to 32

```
public enum FadeDirection
    {
        In,
        Out
    }

    public IEnumerator FadeAndLoadScene(bool fadeDirection, string sceneToLoad)
    {
        yield return Fade(canvasGroup, fadeDirection, false);
```

Then using it in other scripts like this for example :

```
StartCoroutine(sceneFader.FadeAndLoadScene(SceneFader.FadeDirection.In, _newGameButtonLevel));
```

but I'm getting error on :

```
SceneFader.FadeDirection.In
```

cannot convert from SceneFader.FadeDirection to bool

I want to use the fading script also for scene loading. tried to extend it with the enum but getting this error.

The main goal is to be able to fade in/out when loading scene/s and also to fade in out while in the game if just to need to fade in some scenes.

Comment: It's not clear what you expected `FadeDirection.In` to be interpreted as. Since you are using a literal value (not a variable), why not just pass the `bool` value you actually want? If you _did_ have a variable, you could compare it with an enum value to return a `bool` value, but there doesn't seem to be any need to do even that simple conversion here.

Comment: If you're going to have an enum then your public functions should take the enum as a parameter, not a bool. You can convert it to a bool in your internal functions if you need to.

Comment: Is there a reason you are even using an enum here? It seems you have two states one of which is fading in color and the other out, so why not just have a bool `isFadingIn` and set it to true when you are fading in, then false when out? Why do you need to use an enum here at all?

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to do you can consider [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).
You can enhance you enums with functionality like this:

```
public enum Direction {
     north,
     east,
     south,
     west
}

public static class DirectionExtension {
    public static Direction opposite(this Direction dir) {
        return (int)dir < 2 ? (dir + 2) : (dir - 2);
    }

    public static Direction previous(this Direction dir) {
        return dir == Direction.north ? Direction.west : dir - 1;
    }

    public static Direction next(this Direction dir) {
        return dir == Direction.west ? Direction.north : dir + 1;
    }
}
```

For your case,  although you can compare the value of the enum instance wherever in the code, in you could do something like this:

```
public enum FadeDirection {
    In,
    Out
}

public static class FadeDirectionExtension {
    public static bool In(this FadeDirection fadeDir) {
        return fadeDir == FadeDirection.In;
    }

    public static bool Out(this FadeDirection fadeDir) {
        return fadeDir == FadeDirection.Out;
    }
}
```